# How widespread is the pronunciation of "Parmesan" as /ˈpɑɹ.məˌʒɑn/ instead of /ˈpɑɹ.məˌzɑn/?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

The letter *s* in the word [*Parmesan* (meaning the cheese, named after the Parma region of Italy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parmigiano-Reggiano) is pronounced quite widely (Br & Aus AFAIK) as a /z/, per [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parmesan):

- UK, also found in the US: **/ˈpɑɹ.məˌzɑn/**
- found in the US: **/ˈpɑɹ.məˌʒɑn/**

And in Australia (no reference, just experience) it's /ˈpɑɹ.məˌ**z**ɑn/ (maybe heading for /ˈpɑɹ.məˌ**s**ɑn/).

However, in Seattle WA and Portland OR, the locals all (IME) pronounce it with a soft /ʒ/ sound, like in the French *je*, so /ˈpɑɹ.məˌ**ʒ**ɑn/

Is this a "northwest only" variation? How much of the US says /ˈpɑɹ.məˌ**ʒ**ɑn/?

Does this also occur in other countries?

I note that [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Parmesan) includes the spelling pronunciation "-zhan" (albeit last) as an alternative pronunciation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53305/discussion-on-question-by-bohemian-how-widespread-is-the-pronounciation-of-parm).

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/277310 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/282955

Comment: I grew up in Texas and never heard the word pronounced otherwise than with the final syllable "zon." However, my daughter, who grew up in the San Francisco Bay Area of California, always pronounces the word with the final syllable "zhon." All I can say is, she didn't learn that pronunciation at home.